# Svg-edit usage reference where i can find it?

Tags: svg-edit

I found this tool(https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) very useful, but there is any reference for this project allow to integrate properly in your applicatione instead of simply add it to an iframe?
For example i want to retrieve the svg code for save it in a variables or something like this

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but might be a little tricky to strip out the required resources and load them in your own application while making sure that there aren't any conflicts. This is actually something I plan on doing for one of my own projects.

Do you *need* to do this though? You can talk to the iframe from your application pretty easily. For example, to get the SVG content you would use this (assuming you only have 1 iframe on the page) ->

```
var svgedit = window.frames[0];
svgedit.svgCanvas.svgCanvasToString();
```